# Why is the Selenium support class ByIdOrName serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, selenium-webdriver

I would be interested to know why the class 'ByIdOrName' under selenium support serializable?
Any example would really help .I know serialization is the process of converting an object instance into an array of bytes but what purpose would it serve by making this class serializable is what I want to understand and any specific situation when we actually serialise the object of class 'ByIdOrName'?